# Better way to write this XPath expression

Tags: xml, xpath, wireshark

Is there a simpler way to write this XPath expression, specifically the final line. I am searching an XML dump from tshark looking for a certain packet with certain attributes. This is the XPath expression I have

```
count(//packet[
  proto/@name="dhcpv6"
  and .//field/@showname="Message type: Solicit (1)"
  and .//field/@show="Link-layer address: 30:00:01:dc:d9:82"
  and .//field[@show="Interface-Id"]/field[@show="option type: 18"]/../field[@show="Interface-ID: AVC-0123456789"]])
```

This is getting a count of packets that

```
1) Contain a child of <proto name="dhcpv6">
2) Contain a descendant of <field showname="Message type: Solicit (1)/">
3) Contain a descendant of <field show="Link-layer address: 30:00:01:dc:d9:82"/>
4) Contain a descendant of
   <field show="Interface-Id">
     <field show="option type: 18"/>
     <field show="Interface-ID: AVC-0123456789"/>
   </field>
```

The bit I don't like is where it finds "option type: 18" and then goes back to the parent and looks for "Interface-ID: AVC-0123456789". Is there some way to write this with an 'and' statement? It works but is kind of confusing and unreadable IMO.

Here is a simplified version of the XML. Note that the field tags could be within multiple levels which is why I am using .// for these.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<packet>
  <proto name="dhcpv6">
    <field showname="Message type: Solicit (1)"/>
    <field show="Link-layer address: 30:00:01:dc:d9:82"/>
    <field show="Interface-Id">
      <field show="option type: 18"/>
      <field show="Interface-ID: AVC-0123456789"/>
    </field>
  </proto>
</packet>
```

BTW, I am stuck with XPath 1.0 as that is what the tool I am using currently supports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work and makes more sense to me:

```
count(//packet[
    proto/@name="dhcpv6"
    and .//field/@showname="Message type: Solicit (1)"
    and .//field/@show="Link-layer address: 30:00:01:dc:d9:82"
    and .//field[@show="Interface-Id"
        and field[@show="option type: 18"]
        and field[@show="Interface-ID: AVC-0123456789"]
    ]
])
```

Basically the 3rd criteria says:

- field descendant with

  - "show" attribute of "Inferface-Id"
  - child field with "show" attribute of "option type: 18"
  - child field with "show" attribute of "Interface-ID: AVC-0123456789"

You could also write it as follows:

```
count(//packet[
    proto/@name="dhcpv6"
    and .//field/@showname="Message type: Solicit (1)"
    and .//field/@show="Link-layer address: 30:00:01:dc:d9:82"
    and .//field
        [@show="Interface-Id"]
        [field[@show="option type: 18"]]
        [field[@show="Interface-ID: AVC-0123456789"]]
])
```

Which just means that all 3 indented criteria must be met for the third `.//field`.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I'm still learning XPath and didn't realise you could nest the predicates like that. I'm starting to like it more and more. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>  
<xsl:variable name="count" select="count(//packet/proto[@name='dhcpv6' and  /.//field[@showname='Message type: Solicit (1)'] and .//field[@show='Link-layer address: 30:00:01:dc:d9:82']
and .//field[@show='Interface-Id'] and ./field[@show='option type: 18'] and ./field[@show='Interface-ID: AVC-0123456789']])"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<div>
    Count is: <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
</div>


</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, can you tell me what /.// does? I understand .// being a shortcut for descendant::

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately it looks like it doesn't. With the last 3 fields I need to match that exact structure, ie a field with show=Interface-Id and under that the other 2 values specified. With yours I can specify those as 3 fields in any layout and it still matches.

Comment: what if you tried this:  <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(//packet/proto[@name='dhcpv6' and .//field[@showname='Message type: Solicit (1)'] and .//field[@show='Link-layer address: 30:00:01:dc:d9:82']
    and .//field[@show='Interface-Id'] and .//field[@show='option type: 18'] and .//field[@show='Interface-ID: AVC-0123456789']])"/>

Comment: Hi Alex, that is the same issue, the last 2 fields need to be a child of the third last field. That query will match those 3 fields in any location under proto. Even if 'option type: 18' was a parent of 'Interface-Id' it would still match which is not what I want.

Comment: If they are always the direct children then for those two replace .// with just /